# Total number of edges in a triangle mesh with $n$ vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Given a 2D triangle mesh with $n$ vertices, I was wondering if there is an expression that would allow to compute the total number of edges present in the mesh.

For example, the following mesh has 6 vertices and a total of 11 edges:

[image: mesh]

Comment: I think the question is not clear. Will you give some example of a 2D triangle mesh and number of its segments?

Comment: I have added an example for clarity.

Comment: For connected planar graphs, Euler's formula gives us $n-m+f=2$ where $n$ is the number of vertices, $m$ the number of edges, and $f$ the number of faces (including the infinite one). For your example, $n=6, f=7$ which gives $m=11$.

Comment: This seems - to some extent - related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425968/eulers-formula-for-triangle-mesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of vertices alone is not sufficient to determine the number of edges

From [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler.27s_formula)  we know that
$$v-e+f=2,$$
where $v$ is the number of vertices, $e$ is number of edges and $f$ is number of faces (including the outer one).

Now you now additionally, that boundaries of faces have three edges. However, there is one exception, which is the outer face. Let $b$ denote the number of vertices on its boundary (i.e. on the boundary of your mesh). Then you have
$$2e=3(f-1)+b.$$ 
(We count $3$ edges for each inner face, and $b$ edges for the outer face.)

So if you know both $v$ and $b$, you can calculate the number of edges as
$$e=3v-3-b.$$

Some examples
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
  \text{graph} & e & v & b \\\hline
  \text{triangle} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\\hline
  K_4 & 6 & 4 & 3 \\\hline
  \text{diamond} & 5 & 4 & 4 \\\hline
  \text{your mesh} & 11 & 6 & 4 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

$K_4$ is this graph ([complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) on four vertices):

[image: K4]

*Diamond* is this graph:

[image: diamond]

The pictures are taken from [list of small graphs](http://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html).

Comment: Similar (later) post: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/25953/22948